# Authenticating App with OAuth from C#

Tags: c#, oauth

I am writing an app that will talk with Salesforce. Salesforce provides access to APIs via OAuth. I've been attempting to go through the OAuth authentication process described [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com). Currently, I'm attempting to authorize my app. I have the following code.

```
// Ask Salesforce for a request token
var request = (HttpWebRequest)(WebRequest.Create(String.Format("https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={0}&redirect_uri=http://localhost:5004/home/AuthCallback", CONSUMER_KEY)));
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json";

// Retrieve the request token from the response
var response = (HttpWebResponse)(request.GetResponse());
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
  string accessCodeData = accessCodeReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

This code is triggered when a user clicks a button in my ASP.NET MVC view. When executed, this code calls to Salesforce. I see a request in fiddler. The request header looks like this:

```
POST /services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={consumerKey}&redirect_uri=http://localhost:5004/home/AuthCallback HTTP/1.1
```

I am in fact passing my consumer key, I'm just removing it from the example. Regardless, this request returns a 302, with a body size of 0. I might be misunderstanding something. However, I was expecting to get a request token. I was then going to use the request token to get the access token.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misusing the API.

Take a closer look at the sequence diagram at their page (under Obtaining an Access Token): in the auhorization_code flow you are supposed to **redirect** the browser to their page so that the user sees the login page, provides his/her credentials and you get the token back. Instead, you are trying to POST there using a web request from your server.

This particular flow belongs then to the **passive flows** group, this group is intended to be used in browser apps, your server redirects the browser to their server and you basically get the response to the uri passed in the `redirect_uri` parameter and this should point back to your application at your server.

There are other flows, of them one is suited for non-browser apps, it is called **resource owner password** flow. In this flow it is your application that hosts the login UI and you send the username/password to the authorization server and you get the token back. It is to be read in their docs however whether this flow is supported.

Read more here: http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified

Take a look how I handle the OAuth2 flow to Google, using the DotNetOpenAuth library. This is a direct solution, applying it to any other provider should be straightforward.

http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2014/11/simple-oauth2-federated-authentication.html